# Hibernate returns null from getCurrentPrice in outer transactional class

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, orm

Hibernate returns null from getCurrentPrice in outer transactional class.

But new call of get by id returns product with normal current price.

How to fix this?

Here is my Product class

```
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {//...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<OrderItem> orderItems = new HashSet<>();}
```

And OrderItem

```
@Table(name = "orderItems")
public class OrderItem extends BaseModel {//...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "productId")
private Product product;

@Column
private double currentPrice;
}
```

And DAO

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class HibernateOrderDao {//...
public Serializable save(Order order) {
    order.getReceiver().getOrdersToReceive().add(order);
    order.getItems().forEach(item -> {
        item.setOrder(order);
        item.getProduct().getOrderItems().add(item);//todo improve by direct sql or...!
    });
    order.getAddresses().forEach(address -> address.getOrders().add(order));

    return super.save(order);
}
```

But in outer transactional method getCurrentPrice returns null

```
  private Double calculateItemsCost(final OrderItem item) {
    return item.getProduct().getCurrentPrice()
            * item.getQuantity();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can see the id of product, try to call `Product product = productService.findById(item.getProduct().getId())` and then `item.setProduct(product)`

Comment: after  item.getProduct().getOrderItems().add(item); in debug price is also 0

Comment: this will work, but it should run ok without this as I know.

Comment: I dont know if the column in database can have upper letter, try to put as follows: 
`@JoinColumn(name = "productid")`